# Highcharts Date Time With Irregular Intervals Down to Minutes

Tags: datetime, highcharts

I have an array with a date time column that goes down to the second, 2021/10/31 15:12:45, plus other numerical data, temperatures. I have seen lots of HighCharts examples of plotting irregular intervals to the day but not to the hour or minute or second. Is this possible? I sample temperatures every 5 minutes but occasional have a missing time period. Alternatively, is there any way to specify the column in an array to use as the x-axis?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Set your xaxis to type datetime, axes are based on milliseconds, if you want to minutes `pointInterval: 60000 // one minute`

Live demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0pe53jwv/

API References:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickInterval
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.pointStart

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this only seems to change the labeling on the x axis but not the positioning of the points which have a variable time span between each value. If i had three points, 2021/11/01 01:00:00, 2021/11/01 02:00:00, and 2021/11/01 11:00:00 I would expect to see a large gap between the last 2 points but I see three points equally spaced.